# Why doesn't the compiler understand to implicitly cast a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, expression, implicit-conversion

Considering the following sample

```
    public struct EnumSafeExpression<TFunc>
    {
        public Expression<TFunc> SafeExpression { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If we have implicit casting will it 'just work'?
        /// </summary>
        public static implicit operator EnumSafeExpression<TFunc>(Expression<TFunc> ex) => 
            new EnumSafeExpression<TFunc>(ex);

        public EnumSafeExpression(Expression<TFunc> expr)
        {
            Expression madeSafe = // .. blah blah blah;
            SafeExpression = (Expression<TFunc>)madeSafe;
        }
    }

    
    class OtherClassSameNamespace
    {
        Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TEntity>(EnumSafeExpression<Func<TEntity, bool>> enumSafeExpression) where TEntity : class;
    }

    class YetAnotherClass
    {
        void SomeMethod()
        {
            var x = await linqQueryable.SingleOrDefaultAsync<Database>(it => it.Name == name));                            
        }
    }
```

Why does it produce the compiler error

1>C:\repo\RERP\src\Enterprise\RedisProvisioning\Program.cs(186,82,186,103): error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'EnumSafeExpression<Func<Cluster, bool>>' because it is not a delegate type

Instead of finding and using the implicit type conversion operator that was defined?

(But it does not error, when you explicitly cast to expression?)

```
var x = await linqQueryable.SingleOrDefaultAsync<Database>((Expression<Func<Database, bool>>)it => it.Name == name));
```

PS Looks like this should be a limitation of C# 8 [that I'm using] and it could be fixed in C# 10, if the quote below meant what I wanted it to mean. But, when I add `<LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>` to my csproj, it still fails.

> Beginning with C# 10, a lambda expression may have a natural type.
> Instead of forcing you to declare a delegate type, such as Func<...>
> or Action<...> for a lambda expression, the compiler may infer the
> delegate type from the lambda expression. For example, consider the
> following declaration:
>
> C#
>
> Copy var parse = (string s) => int.Parse(s); The compiler can infer
> parse to be a Func<string, int>. The compiler chooses an available
> Func or Action delegate, if a suitable one exists. Otherwise, it
> synthesizes a delegate type. For example, the delegate type is
> synthesized if the lambda expression has ref parameters. When a lambda
> expression has a natural type, it can be assigned to a less explicit
> type, such as System.Object or System.Delegate: